# Java equivalent of Crypto Charm ECGroup serialize / deserialize

Tags: java, python, bouncycastle, charm-crypto

I am new to cryptography and am learning how to use Bouncy Castle in Java for crypto purposes.

I know that Python has Crypto-Charm which I have used

```
import charm.toolbox.ecgroup


serializedKey = charm.toolbox.ecgroup(prime192v1).deserialize(keyInBytes)
```

How can I do the same for Java?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Deserialize:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

Serialize:

```
byte[] keyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
```

Maybe you can need this call (depending on your JDK) previous to KeyFactory.getInstance:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Answer (score 0):

This reference could be useful https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BCFipsIn100.pdf to understand different examples of code enconding.

In chapter

> Password Based Encryption and Key Storage

on this section

> Encoding Public and Private Keys

there are some examples to get ideas.